# Inject Chakra UI's global style with a specific scope

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I would like to embed a React application that uses Chakra UI into a website, but Chakra's global style affects the entire website.

Is there a way to inject Chakra's global style with a specific scope?

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you would need to use your own css reset to scope it. There is an [existing codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hs31q) that could be useful, that I didn't author.

1. Disable the default css reset on `<ChakraProvider />`

```
<ChakraProvider resetCSS={false}>
  <div className="chakra-reset">
    ...
  </div>
</ChakraProvider>
```

2. Add your own reset css that targets `.chakra-reset`. You could use [this](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/components/css-reset/src/css-reset.tsx) and scope it.